# WPF ManagementScope Access denied

Tags: asp.net, .net, wpf, wmi

I have followed [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cbd93b81-2c23-4363-a00e-f702d6fa1349/managementscopeconnect-giving-an-error-quotaccess-denied-exception-from-hresult-0x80070005?forum=vbgeneral) to make my application to connect to other machine but failed. The problems as I encountered is:

1. "RPC Server Unavailable". I fixed it after using: `Netsh firewall set service RemoteAdmin`
2. Then I got "Access denied". While  trying to fix this, I found out my Remote Desktop Control (RDC) got connection error too, but I managed to fix that RDC by goto "System properties -> Allow remote connections to this computer" [image: Here the demo]

Here is my simplified code:

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Username = userName;
options.Password = password;
scope = new ManagementScope(string.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", computerName), options);
scope.Connect();
```

***Updated 1***
I ran WMI diag tool as @Rox suggested in the comment and [these](https://justpaste.it/8gt89) are the logs files generated.
***Updated 2***
I found out my error code (HResult) is -2146233087 but such error code doesn't exist on google

Comment: Make shure wmiservice is enabled on remotemachine under services

Comment: do you mean wmi performance adapter ? I have a screen shot of my services [here](https://ibb.co/K58NBN8)

Comment: winmgmt and dcom

Comment: https://www.poweradmin.com/help/faqs/how-to-enable-wmi-for-remote-access/

Comment: Is any Antivirus blocking?

Comment: 'wmic /node:192.168.0.24 path win32_operatingsystem get caption  '    replace with your IP and Start it with sufficient Rights. If this is not connecting your config is bad, otherwise your code

Comment: What is the result from wmic mentioned above?

Comment: @RoXTar The result is "ERROR: Description = Access is denied"

Comment: Ok so its your computerconfiguration, not your code

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7684 try this on remotepc

Comment: What about domain or workgroup?

Comment: @RoXTar I ran the tool you suggested and updated the logs file in the post, please check

Comment: Please excuse my bad English if it make you feel uncomfortable

Comment: BTW, window is not activated on my client machine, will that effect anything?

Comment: First! The Logs include sensible Information. Second your userrights are possibly  insufficient. Why is your user admin @ admin with computername admin? This condtellation is uggly. I suggest an Installation with same Domain or workgroup or you have to provide Domain/workgroup

Comment: The Log says insufficient Rights. Did you run it with "run as admin" ?

Comment: I ran with adminstrator and updated the log in the link

Comment: Ok, with correct rights your connection is succesfull, but your wmi seems to have errors.  With same admin AND NTLMDomain you should try to connect from your other client. Try it with wmic first. Use wmic with this admin and domain opr workgroup. Your ntlmdomain seems to be admin :-) Note: wmi on local machine needs "Run as Admin", but remoteconnections need name and pass

Comment: Thanks, after reading up on your domain thing, I tried to set up AD Domain, but I ran into a problem with it (yet again), can you have a look there please, this thing is really a config rabit-hole to me https://superuser.com/questions/1578628/connect-to-domain-of-windows-server-2016-on-vmware

Comment: I make it work by importing local security policy of a wmi enabled computer to the disabled machine. You can refer to the differences if interested [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/V6lWAGN0) left is the worked policies and right is the non-worked policies. Anyways, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make it work by importing Local Security Policy of a computer that my code can connect. [Here](https://justpaste.it/1utds) is my config that works

Comment: glad you solved it with configuring your machine right bud.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your options:

```
ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions(); 
connOptions.Username = userName; 
connOptions.Password = password;
connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate; 
connOptions.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy; 
connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
```

**Edit**
For connections to local machine you don't have to use username and password,  but you have to start app with sufficient rights

Best regards